# Irregular behavior for next CollectionView item after disabling buttons

Tags: debugging, swiftui, swiftui-button

I'm currently using a SwiftUI View through `UIHostingConfiguration` as a `UICollectionViewCell`. Each cell is a trivia question, so I would like to disable all `AnswerButton` items once the user has selected one of them. I attempted to do so through adding `@Binding var isDisabled: Bool` to my `AnswerButton` and triggering `.disabled(isDisabled == true)` once the button is tapped. I'm passing this value as a `@State var isDisabled: Bool = false` from the `QuestionCardView`. During testing I noticed that the last `QuestionCardView` in the collection appears already disabled. Not sure which part of the process is causing the issue. Each `QuestionCardView` should be self reliant, so I'm unsure how the behavior is being passed over to the next cell. Any Advice would be appreciated!

QuestionCardView Code:

```
struct QuestionCardView: View {
    var question: QuestionModel
    @State var isDisabled: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text(question.attributedTextFromHTML ?? "")
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
                ForEach(question.allAnswers, id: \.self) {
                    AnswerButton(answer: $0, isDisabled: $isDisabled)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .safeAreaPadding(.all)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(Configuration.opacity))
        .cornerRadius(Configuration.cornerRadius)
    }
}
```

AnswerButton Code:

```
struct AnswerButton: View {
    var answer: Answer
    @State private var didTap: Bool = false
    @Binding var isDisabled: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            didTap = true
            isDisabled = true
        }) {
            HStack(spacing: Configuration.spacing) {
                Text(answer.text)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .contentShape(Capsule())
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: Configuration.maxHeight)
            .background(didTap ? (answer.isCorrect ? .green : .red) : .gray)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
        }
        .disabled(isDisabled == true)
    }
}
```

I tried moving the `.disabled(isDisabled == true)` to the `QuestionCardView` but it was less reliable. I'm expecting each card to appear with `isDisabled` set to false but the last card always appears disabled. When I apply breakpoints I sometimes receive an `AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute` warning, so that is most likely involved. The warning only happens when breakpoints are active though.